# Coredata or Sqlite which is better

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Can you please help to choose from Coredata or sqlite ??
Which one is better ? As I have complex query in database.

Comment: No, we can't help you choose. You need to make your own research and decide using the criteria specific to your project.

Answer (score 2):

This blog will help you a little

http://blog.mcohen.me/2010/06/19/why-i-chose-sqlite-instead-of-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

The answer, of course, is that "it depends". They both have their advantages and disadvantages depending on what you want to achieve.

Check out this article, and others, on choosing between the two: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1959-when-to-use-sqlite-instead-of-core-data-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is a RDMS system and involves SQL and while CoreData is a object-oriented programming within xcode.. Both deal with a lot of data in the database. Both have their own way of writing and saving to the database. You need to know their specific ways... On deciding on which to use, it really depends on the circumstance you are in.. If you are using a simple query or have very little data in the database, you could use plist or userdefaults. The choice is yours because you know best what you need...